# Which package should I use after classes in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console are removed

Tags: .net-core

I have legacy code like this:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.Internal;

...

IConsole console1 = new WindowsLogConsole();
IConsole console2 = new AnsiLogConsole(new AnsiSystemConsole());
```

`WindowsLogConsole` and `AnsiLogConsole` can be found in old version here:
https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/8270c545224e8734d7297e54edef5c584ee82f01/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/Internal

But now they are all gone: https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/tree/master/src/Logging

What's the suggested approach that I change my legacy logging code?